# Issue passing list records to another method

Tags: apex

I am having an issue passing a result list from 1 method to another.

```
public list<Cand__c> tc1;
public list<Cand__c> newcand;
public set<id> candId = new Set<id>();

public void StartHere() {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
             tc1 = [
                SELECT Id, Tasks__c, (SELECT Id FROM Actions__r)
                FROM Cand__c
                WHERE id IN :candId
            ];
            if (tc1.size() > 0) {
               TaskRollUps(tc1);
            }
        }
        }

public void TaskRollUps( newcand) {
newcand.Action_Tasks__c = null;
```

I have tried updating the `public void TaskRollUps( newcand) to public void TaskRollUps(List<Cand__c> newcand)`

But no luck.  I keep getting the error variable does not exist in the TaskRollUps method.  I originally had the query in the Starthere method in a for loop to iterate through the candid but I assumed this was not best practice but not sure if I am getting all of the records associated to candid set. 
I was assuming since the list where public that I can easily pass them to other methods but I have not been able to.
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you are receiving a List as a parameter on the TaskRollUps method but are trying to access the Action_Tasks__c as if it was a single object.

Besides updating the `public void TaskRollUps( newcand) to public void TaskRollUps(List<Cand__c> newcand)` you should also iterate over the newcand list and update the values of the records contained on the list.

Edit: I also believe you need to add the Action_Tasks__c field to the original query otherwise you won't be able to access those values.

```
public list < Cand__c > tc1;
public list < Cand__c > newcand;
public set < id > candId = new Set < id > ();

public void StartHere() {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        tc1 = [
            SELECT Id, Action_Tasks__c, Tasks__c, (SELECT Id FROM Actions__r)
            FROM Cand__c
            WHERE id IN: candId
        ];
        if (tc1.size() > 0) {
            TaskRollUps(tc1);
        }
    }
}

public void TaskRollUps(List <Cand__c> newcand) {
    for (Cand__c cand: newcand) {
        cand.Action_Tasks__c = null;
    }
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: That worked and makes sense.  I wanted to confirm.  If a list is made public it should be accessible throughout the class correct?  I ask this because within the rollup method I am taking the values from cand variable and  trying to add them to another list.  ToUpdated.add(cand);  But I get a null pointer error(Attempt to de-reference a null object).  In the debug log I can values in the cand variable so I am not sure why I am getting the error.  Thank you for working with me threw this.

Comment: Hello @Phuc, can you please paste here the complete code?

Comment: I believe I resolved my issue but I have a question.  What is the difference between Public list<Cand__c>;  and Public list<Cand__c> = new <Cand__c>?  The reason I ask is because I have Public list<Cand__c> tc and I have it in a method where I am populating it with a query.  tc = [query string].  But if I want to perform an action like this ToUpdated.add(cand);  I have to declare the list like this  public List<Cand__c> ToUpdate = new List<Cand__c>();  Why is that?

Comment: According to the [documentation on variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm), "If you declare a variable and don't initialize it with a value, it will be null." 
That way, if you do not initialize it you will have a null reference instead of an empty list.